# Find if a record exists in Hive table

Tags: hive

I want to insert a record in **hive** table but before inserting it i want to check if it that record already exists in the table.  that case i won't insert the record and would rather skip it.

Hive version i am using is `Hive 1.1.0.`

**Table structure:**

```
      hk                | diagnosisid  |    id   | cdcode
-----------------------------------------------------------
EXVWLOORV@#19690321F    |       1      |   7810  |    I9C
OHQQDUG@#19380630F      |       1      |   3643  |    I9C
VPLWK@#19610120F        |       1      |   2731  |    I9C
```

before inserting the record i want to check if the `hk` value is already present or not in the hive table.

Comment: Which version hive you have, also provide the table structure.

Comment: @Vivek i have updated my question. Please check.

Comment: From where you are inserting the data, some application? I guess?

Comment: i am parsing the file using spark & then inserting in hive table.

Comment: Will be able to write the IF condition there and loop there??

Comment: i want to write this check in Hive command itself. while inserting the record in hive table i want to check if how it can be done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170667/discussion-between-vivek-and-ironman).

Comment: I have updated the answer try it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach:::1:**

If you can write the "IF and LOOP" then you can try this approach.

```
select count(1) as cnt
from yourtable
where hk='new_value';

if (cnt=0){
---your insert query will be here
}else {
   --some message... "hk" already present in table.
}
```

**Approach:::2:**

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name
      (hk, diagnosisid, id, cdcode)
SELECT 'asdf' as hk,
       'asdf' as diagnosisid,
       'ss'   as id,
       'ddww' as cdcode
 WHERE 'asdf' 
        NOT IN (SELECT hk FROM your_table_name)
```

**Approach:::3:**

Then finally you have to write ETL script to perform the actions.

**Solution:**

**In your scenario: (as per table provided in comments) Query will be:**

```
create table pid1(hk string,diagnosisid string,id string,cdcode string);
insert into pid1 values('EXVWLOORV@#19690321F','1','7810','I9C');
insert into pid1 values('OHQQDUG@#19380630F','1','3643','I9C');
insert into pid1 values('VPLWK@#19610120F','1','2731','I9C');

create table pid as select * from pid1 limit 1;

INSERT INTO pid
      (hk, diagnosisid, id, cdcode)
SELECT hk,
       diagnosisid,
       id,
       cdcode
from pid1
 WHERE hk NOT IN (SELECT hk FROM pid);
```

All the best!!!

Comment: I recommend going for Approach 2, or 3.

Comment: Thanks for the help.But i have the data in one table i want to move it in another table that time i want to find the record. In that case SELECT 'asdf' as hrk will not work because i already have the results in one table.

Comment: "asdf" is the sample for processing your SQL, select the column that you want to insert instead of sample columns, then add FROM clause to get the data from table and again add your column in where condition.

Comment: Or update your Source table name, target table name with their columns. I will make one SQL for you.

Comment: i am getiing  `Correlating expression cannot contain unqualified column references`

Comment: :) Share the source and target table name. or update the query what you made from my suggestion.

Comment: target table name: `PID1`
source table name : `PID`
sorry if my question sounds noob

Comment: I have updated the exact query try it now, will solve your problem

Comment: I tried i am getting `Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'hk': Correlating expression cannot contain unqualified column references.`

Comment: which version of hive you are using?

Comment: hive 1.1.0 version

Comment: I have updated the answer with create Table, insert, create as, and finally insert. try it on your hive once and let me know what happen, I am using hive 2.2.0. might due to version conflict.

Comment: still same issue

Comment: If you can upgrade the hive then it will work, else you have to do somethinng else. I don't know.

Comment: I did little modification in your code `INSERT INTO pid
      (hk, diagnosisid, id, cdcode)
SELECT pid1.hk,
       diagnosisid,
       id,
       cdcode
from pid1
 WHERE pid1.hk NOT IN (SELECT hk FROM pid);`
with this my code is running but in the table i am not getting any data.

Comment: It seems that you have not try my any of solution, what you are commenting now that I have already given before an hour. :) NP.... All the best

Comment: no i have tried it can you please see closely i have added `pid1.hk` instead of `hk` then  it worked. I don't want to waste your time.Any way i am upvoting your answer. I am also accepting it. You also upvote my question if you find it good.

Comment: thats not a problem in 2.2.0, you can try, its not mandatory.

Comment: ok but in this version it worked this way. Thanks a lot for your help. I would upgrade my hive version.